# what does "I think it was par for the course" mean

Tags: meaning, expressions

In an interview ElonMusk says the following about steve jobs(http://www.freshdialogues.com/2013/02/25/elon-musk-on-steve-jobs-innovation-critics-transcript/).

```
I think it was par for the course
```

What does it mean. Googling for **par** shows the following. But none of those meaning fits with the sentence. What does it mean.

```
par
pɑː/
noun
noun: par; plural noun: pars

    1.
    Golf
    the number of strokes a first-class player should normally require for a particular hole or course.
    "Woosnam had advanced from his overnight position of three under par"
        a par score at a hole.
        "a card that showed 16 pars, one eagle, and one birdie"
    2.
    Stock Exchange
    the face value of a share or other security, as distinct from its market value.
    "the 9 per cent unsecured loan stock is redeemable at par"
        the recognized value of one country's currency in terms of another's.
        noun: par of exchange; plural noun: pars of exchange

verb
Golf
verb: par; 3rd person present: pars; past tense: parred; past participle: parred; gerund or present participle: parring

    1.
    play (a hole) in par.
    "he calmly parred the 17th"
```

Origin

Comment: I think this is General Reference. From OxfordDictionariesOnline: [**par for the course**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/par-for-the-course) - *What is normal or expected in any given circumstances*. It's a trivial figurative extension from the golf score sense *(par = standard)*. In OP's case, the guy says Steve Jobs was rude him, but he to didn't take it personally because apparently Jobs was habitually rude to many people (so it was only to be expected).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The golf reference is the one that fits. "Par for the course" means "I took as many hits as would be expected for the course", and it is used symbolically for:

> The effort or the result was what was to be expected; it was not much more or much less than expected.

In general it means: it went as well as one would expect, it did not go extremely well, it did not go very bad.

Answer (score 0):

Saying that something is "par for the course" implies that it is the average or expected outcome.